# Automating mouse clicks on screen

Tags: c#, .net, windows, automation

I am looking for a way of creating a program that will perform a mouse click where it finds a certain color on the screen.

For example if there is a red box on the screen, I would want the program to click on the red box in the center of it.

How could I accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Sorry? I do not understand a word.

Comment: You need to further clarify what you mean. Are you going to tell it where to click or does it have to find the red box somehow? What if there are two red boxes? How many pixels constitues a "box" etc

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I am not looking for a solution so much, just a way of achieving it, for this case there would only be one red box on the screen

Comment: @JamesTeare So technically, you could just find a single red pixel on the screen, click on it, and stop?

Comment: Will mouse click be processed by your application or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you only wanted a general way, I didn't really make it perfect, but here is the idea:

Have a method for taking a screen shot:

```
public Bitmap ScreenShot()
{
    var screenShot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(screenShot))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
    }

    return screenShot;
}
```

And a method to find a certain color in a bitmap:
Note that this implementation can be DRASTICALLY improved using unsafe code and LockBits (read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx)).

```
public Point? GetFirstPixel(Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(color))
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Another method you'll need is one for clicking a certain point:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",
           CharSet=CharSet.Auto,
           CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags,
                                      long dx,
                                      long dy,
                                      long cButtons,
                                      long dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

public void Click(Point pt)
{
    Cursor.Position = pt;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0);
}
```

And finally, one to wrap it all up:

```
public bool ClickOnFirstPixel(Color color)
{
    var pt = GetFirstPixel(ScreenShot(), color);

    if (pt.HasValue)
    {
        Click(pt.Value);
    }

    // return whether found pixel and clicked it
    return pt.HasValue;
}
```

Then, the usage would be:

```
if (ClickOnFirstPixel(Color.Red))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found a red pixel and clicked it!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't find a red pixel, didn't click.");
}
```